# Subquery top X of random rows not working (MS ACCESS)

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm doing a subquery to select the top 5 of products for each supplier. The selection needs to be done randomly on the products for each supplier.

For this I have made the following query (based on Allen Browne's example):

```
SELECT tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, tblProducts_temp.GTIN
FROM tblProducts_temp
GROUP BY tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, tblProducts_temp.GTIN
HAVING (((tblProducts_temp.GTIN) In (SELECT TOP 5 Dupe.GTIN 
FROM tblProducts_temp AS Dupe 
WHERE Dupe.SupplierID = tblProducts_temp.SupplierID 
ORDER BY RND(Dupe.GTIN) DESC)))
ORDER BY tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, tblProducts_temp.GTIN;
```

The query returns a random number of products, but not a top 5. So for supplier X one time 3 products and the next time for supplier X 7 products.

The query without the RND function, so just the top 5 works fine:

```
SELECT tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, tblProducts_temp.GTIN
FROM tblProducts_temp
GROUP BY tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, tblProducts_temp.GTIN
HAVING (((tblProducts_temp.GTIN) In (SELECT TOP 5 Dupe.GTIN 
FROM tblProducts_temp AS Dupe 
WHERE Dupe.SupplierID = tblProducts_temp.SupplierID 
ORDER BY Dupe.GTIN DESC)))
ORDER BY tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, tblProducts_temp.GTIN;
```

I'am real stuck. Can anyone please help me out!

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If the `Rnd()` seems to be messing up the `TOP 5` in the same query then you could try moving the `Rnd()` into its own subquery, perhaps like this (untested)?

```
SELECT 
    tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, 
    tblProducts_temp.GTIN
FROM tblProducts_temp
GROUP BY 
    tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, 
    tblProducts_temp.GTIN
HAVING 
    tblProducts_temp.GTIN IN 
        (
            SELECT TOP 5 Dupe.GTIN 
            FROM 
                (
                    SELECT GTIN, Rnd(GTIN) AS rndSeq
                    FROM tblProducts_temp AS t3
                    WHERE t3.SupplierID = tblProducts_temp.SupplierID
                ) AS Dupe 
            ORDER BY Dupe.rndSeq DESC
        )
ORDER BY 
    tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, 
    tblProducts_temp.GTIN;
```

### Edit

I experimented with several different variations on the theme of the query above, and it appears that having a dynamic `Rnd()` function in that sort of subquery really does confuse the database engine. I suspect that it is because as the subquery is called repeatedly the `Rnd()` values change each time, and therefore the "sort order" of the records in in flux.

A solution to that problem would be to create the [tblProducts_temp] table with an `AutoNumber(Random)` Primary Key field (named [rndID] in the example below), so when the [SupplierID] and [GTIN] values are INSERTed via something like this...

```
INSERT INTO tblProducts_temp ( SupplierID, GTIN )
SELECT tblProducts.SupplierID, tblProducts.GTIN
FROM tblProducts;
```

...then each row in [tblProducts_temp] has a random key value that is persistent (and unchanging, at least for the duration of the task at hand):

```
rndID        SupplierID  GTIN
-----------  ----------  ----
-1615446985           1     1
  132251564           1     2
  -43091651           1     3
-1416094278           1     4
  552752563           1     5
-1319640456           1     6
 1743429401           1     7
  409890150           2     1
 1563614959           2     2
 1727785476           2     3
 -611861835           2     4
 1826254802           2     5
-1118022677           2     6
 -530587056           2     7
```

With that in place, the original query in the question can be made to work by simply replacing `ORDER BY RND(Dupe.GTIN)` with `ORDER BY Dupe.rndID`:

```
SELECT 
    tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, 
    tblProducts_temp.GTIN
FROM tblProducts_temp
GROUP BY 
    tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, 
    tblProducts_temp.GTIN
HAVING tblProducts_temp.GTIN In 
    (
        SELECT TOP 5 Dupe.GTIN 
        FROM tblProducts_temp AS Dupe 
        WHERE Dupe.SupplierID = tblProducts_temp.SupplierID 
        ORDER BY Dupe.rndID DESC
    )
ORDER BY 
    tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, 
    tblProducts_temp.GTIN;
```

Comment: Nice insight. It does'nt do the trick though, because it does not recognize tblProducts_temp.SupplierID in the subquery (?). It asks for the parameter tblProducts_temp.SupplierID, when running the query.